# Configure scheduler special condition

Tags: spring, spring-boot, schedule

I need a special scheduler. I want to solve my problem by the using spring boot schedule.
My problem:

- every 8am start to work

- if scheduler start, every hour call a function

- evening 10pm finish.

Comment: Hi! Could you please provide code of what you've already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See in [online cron generator](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html)

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 8-22 ? * *")
```

> At second :00, at minute :00, every hour between 08am and 22pm, of every day